# How can I swap in and out text inside a DIV using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have text inside a DIV like this:

```
<div>

@*<p class="header">xxx</p>
<p>
yyy
</p>
<p>
yyy
</p>*@

<p class="header">xxx</p>
<p>
yyy
</p>
<p>
yyy
</p>

</div>
```

I commented out the first three paragraphs and replaced them with the second three. Is there a way I could make it so that every ten seconds it changes between showing the first three paragraphs and the second three. Note that I don't use jQuery on this page. I want to find a solution that does not use jQuery.

Comment: please read: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I am happy to try anything based on some hints but unfortunately don't have a good knowledge of javascript and the DOM which is why I am hoping to get some advice.

Comment: rather `setInterval` as it has to be done _every_ 10 seconds

Comment: Look at the JavaScript function called `setInterval` to assist with you time, but can you expand on why you do not want to use jQuery?

Comment: @Luke If she is new to JS then it is much better to start with no-framework env to learn the language. Also IMHO jQuery is mostly unnecessary overhead, personally I prefer [vanilla-js framework](http://vanilla-js.com) ;)

Comment: @lupatus true, I agree you should have some background understanding of JavaScript to appreciated what jQuery and other frameworks do for you. That vanilla code for fade out makes me go cross-eyed! Speeds are impressive though. Just wanted to check it wasn't a company policy of some sort.

Comment: We've not used jQuery for anything so the thinking was it would be overkill to use it for just this one thing. Thanks for advice so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without jQuery:**

Put the two groups of

in two div with their id.

```
document.getElementById('idDiv1').style.display = "none"; --> make invisibile the div1
document.getElementById('idDiv2').style.display = "block"; --> make visibile the div2
```

For make this in automatic mode, you have to use timer function of javascript, look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). This is a link of W3School.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) functions.

The first allows you to define code to be executed when a timeout ends, the 2nd will keep executing the specified code until you stop it.

As for *replacing the content of a tag without jquery*, i will leave that as an exercise for you. :)